# Is there a way to relaunch the camera service on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm working on a simple camera application that will need to run for a long time, but take a single picture occasionally. The problem is the camera services goes to sleep or dies when the app runs for a long time.

When it goes to sleep, minimising the app and restoring it does the trick (as the camera is released `onPause` and opened again `onResume`). I've started my app from the CameraPreview sample which felt stable.

Other times the camera server dies (error 100) and I couldn't find a callback to listen for that. Rarely restarting the app resolves this, but most of the time rebooting the device is the only fix.

Is there a command to restart/relaunch libcameraservice without rebooting the device ?

If so, how ?